# Why does multithreaded writing to a Vec<HashSet<&str>> using raw pointers segfault?

Tags: multithreading, pointers, rust

I want to modify a big vector from multiple threads in parallel.

### Works fine: `u32`

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let input = Arc::new([1u32, 2, 3, 4]);

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for t in 0..4 {
        let inp = input.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
            let p = (inp.as_ptr() as *mut u32).offset(t as isize);
            *p = inp[t] + t as u32 ;
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

### Segfaults: `Vec<HashSet<&str>>`

When I change the `u32` to `Vec<HashSet<&str>>`, the pointer does not seem to work.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {

    let mut a = HashSet::new();
    a.insert("aaa");
    let input = Arc::new(vec![a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone()]);

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for _t in 0..4 {
        let inp = input.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
            let p = (inp.as_ptr() as *mut Vec<HashSet<&str>>).offset(0);
            (*p)[0].insert("bbb");
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: 1. Please explain what you mean by "works bad": what you expect, and what you get instead.
2. Your code examples are identical.
3. You are casting a shared reference to a mut pointer to a mutable reference. This seems pretty dangerous.

Comment: sorry, I paste the same code  by mistake, It has been fixed. I know it's dangerous, but if change to Mutex+lock, It will degenerate into a single thread. there "works bad" means do nothing, error reporting nothing.

Comment: I have added an answer that avoids `unsafe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what is wrong with your initial code as it [segfaults in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13ca6a6ae9c5d0273d7404b10515b218). You are likely invoking undefined behavior by taking a reference to immutable (!) vec and trying to mutate its elements by casting `&Vec` -> `*mut Vec` -> `&mut Vec` (on a method call). Multiple mutable references to the same thing are a big no-no. Besides, your code even uses the same `HashSet` (`(*p)[0]`) mutably in parallel, which, again, is undefined behavior.

The easiest way here would be to use crossbeam's scoped threads. They allow referencing stack variables, like your `input`. `Vec` can also give out distinct mutable references to its elements without using `unsafe`. Using this, your code seems to do the expected thing.

```rust
use crossbeam::thread;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut a = HashSet::new();
    a.insert("aaa");
    let mut input = vec![a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone()];

    thread::scope(|s| {
        for set in &mut input {
            s.spawn(move |_| {
                set.insert("bbb");
            });
        }
    }).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found the way:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut a = HashSet::new();
    a.insert("aaa");
    let input = Arc::new(vec![a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone(), a.clone()]);

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for _t in 0..4 {
        let inp = input.clone();
        //let out = output.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
            let p = (inp.as_ptr() as *mut Vec<HashSet<&str>>).offset(0);

            (*p)[0].insert("bbb");
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }


    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", input);
}
```

thanks for guys!

Comment: This again seems like the same code as in your initial question.